# Amazon EC2 change instance type, possible issues with volumes?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need to change the instance type of my AWS EC2 instance and I know that it's quite simple :
Stop instance -> change instance type -> start it -> associate elastic IP

My concern is about the volumes of my instance.
I have 2 volumes mounted and the type change may affect it.

Any tips to do a safe instance change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the volumes are EBS volumes then you can safely do this (note that terminating an instance can delete EBS volumes if they have the delete on termination flag set, but stopping an instance is ok). The volumes will stay attached to the instance but depending on the operating system and configuration you may need to remount them

If they are ephemeral volumes then stopping the instance will lose all data stored on them.

Comment: Thanks ! Will the "new" instance keep my 2 volumes attached/mounted like it was before ? Or will I need to redo the configuration ?

Comment: They'll stay attached, you may need to mount them

Comment: I just tested it and everything went fine, no need to mount them again.

Comment: @FrederickCheung If I have an elastic IP for the current instance type, do I want to configure it again after changing to new instance?